# mp3 support on Xubuntu 20.04 / guaydeque

Tags: 20.04, mp3, music-player, flac

I just installed Xubuntu 20.04, and am currently working to get mp3/flac-support going. First, I did install various players to try the look & feel (Clementine, Rhythmbox, QuodLibet ...) & settled for guayadeque in the end (would have prefered gmusicbrowser, but, alas...)

Anyway: Guayadeque does play ogg, ape, most other formats, some (but not all?!) flac, but no mp3. I did install, purge and reinstall restricted extras & addons, but to no avail...

vlc and parole do play all, but those suck as music browsers! (I got a large collection of 70.000 songs, so I need extended DB-type search & other capabilities).

So: What to do, where to look?

Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

About gmusicbrowser - it [was removed](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gmusicbrowser&searchon=names) from the repositories after Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but you can still install it by manual package download:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gmusicbrowser/gmusicbrowser_1.1.15~ds0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./gmusicbrowser_1.1.15~ds0-1_all.deb
```

I have just tested it with 3000+ tracks library on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

---

As far I know Guayadeque is not available in the official repositories, but exists in the [author's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~anonbeat/+archive/ubuntu/guayadeque).
So you can [ask author](https://launchpad.net/%7Eanonbeat/+contactuser) about formats support in the latest builds.
On my system MP3s are played normally from Guayadeque 0.4.6.r2140.b08bddd~focal-1.
Also make sure that you really have installed `xubuntu-restricted-addons` / `ubuntu-restricted-addons` packages with all codecs.